# ASP.NET Compilation Error when accessing variable located in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a variable set in the code behind:

```
public string loggedInUserId { get; set; }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loggedInUserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
}
```

When I run in debug mode, it's fine, the var gets the user correctly.

I have this piece of Javascript which gets a value from a rating system, it then calls a WCF service:

```
var loggedinuserid = "<%=loggedInUserId%>";
SaveRatingService.Save(score, walkID, loggedInUserID);
```

Again, locally this run fine. However, when I publish to the server and try access the page I get this:

[image]

Full error log:

```
CS1061: 'ASP.walks_walkdetails_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'loggedInUserId' and no extension method 'loggedInUserId' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.walks_walkdetails_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Why is it doing this? I've tried manually registering the variable in the `WalkDetails.aspx.designer.cs` file, but it moans that it's already registered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your "publish" went 100% correctly? This looks very much like the exact problem you'd have when your dll doesn't get replaced properly on the server.

Comment: Actually, as I know, code behind's loading occurs after design page's loading. So in your case firstly your javascript function is gonna be occur, but this does not aware of loggedInUserId variable.

Comment: @Paul-Jan I've tried uploading it multiples times and it said 'successfully published. I'll try again, but do a FULL publish (rather than single value). I'll then investigate directly through FTP and get back to you

Comment: @Khazratbek I have got the variable in a function that runs on `$(document).ready(function(){...}`. Shouldn't that prevent what you said from happening?

Comment: Are you app pools the same (locally, and on the server)? Specifically the managed pipeline mode and the .NET framework version...

Comment: @Paul-Jan OK it's not a publishing issue, I've manually checked the file and it seems to be uploading fine

Comment: @Balah could you elaborate. Where would  I check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's that extra ">" at the end of "<%=this.loggedInUserId%>";**>**

**EDIT:**
Ok, since you're describing a problem which only happens in your deployment server (and NOT in your local development machine), if I were you I'd naturally suspect the deployment machine.

Do you have any indication that your deployment was successful? How do you deploy - are you manually copying your entire project/solution to the **wwwroot**, or are you simply deploying with Visual Studio's web deployment tool? Because it looks like your server-side code does not contain the definition of '**loggedInUserId**'.

In case you're using Visual Studio's deployment tool, and you're using a Windows-based server as a deployment target - can you verify that the DLLs which your project produces are properly installed in the server's Windows\Assembly folder?

Comment: sorry, that was actually a typo on my behalf, I've updated the question now

Answer (score 0):

Usually I define global variable for the page: `public string varVal = "";` and then create some method in code behind to take a variable's value (as following):

```
public string GetVariableValue(){
    varVal = "myValue";
}
```

And then in design page, in javascript (it is just example):

```
alert('<%=GetVariableValue()%>');
```